# Webview Swipe issue - Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

Right now I am using one webview to show data from my aplicationDatadirectory, here everything is working fine, I get content when user click next back respectively. Now what I am doing is in onload of webview I register "touchevent" and "touchmove" in webview's html like this :-

```
$.webview.evalJS('document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("touchstart", function mytouch(){Ti.App.fireEvent("touch", {X:event.touches[0].pageX,Y:event.touches[0].pageY,length:event.touches.length});}, false);'); 
$.webview.evalJS('document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("touchmove", function mymove(){Ti.App.fireEvent("move", {X:event.touches[0].pageX,Y:event.touches[0].pageY,length:event.touches.length});}, false);');
```

on the basis of this I find swipe event. I get correct html in webview(I can see images). But I am unable to get touchstart and move call. I dont know what is the problem here. I set data in webview using url here.

Now when I set data in webview using html(I used data of my html file(given below) in one var) now I am unable to see images it just shows me one black border(empty) but here my touchstart and touchmove events are firing also my swipe is also working as expected. I am checking this functionality in iPhone.

Can any one find the issue what is going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Edit :- while using webview.html I copied image to resource folder and then check and swipe is working(That black empty border was for not getting image I think). But when I use webview.url its not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it swipe working in iOS(in android it was working).
I did not expect this thing to be a reason but I do not know logic behind it. I was accessing .xhtml files from application data directory and it was working without any issue in android but in iOS it was not.

I just change(rename in my code) .xhtml file to .html and now it is working. :) 
Hope this can help someone who is looking for the same.(or just for his interest)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this depends on the time when you apply

```
$.webview.evalJS('document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("touchstart", function mytouch(){Ti.App.fireEvent("touch", {X:event.touches[0].pageX,Y:event.touches[0].pageY,length:event.touches.length});}, false);'); 
$.webview.evalJS('document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("touchmove", function mymove(){Ti.App.fireEvent("move", {X:event.touches[0].pageX,Y:event.touches[0].pageY,length:event.touches.length});}, false);');
```

If you use the `html` property data is loaded immediately and you can use the code exactly after setting `html` content. If you use the `url` (even if it is located locally, which might be difficult for android) then you need to wait a short time until the page is loaded. There is also an event listener for that (web view-event `load`) but i can't say if that works for local resources but i don't think so.

In this case you should apply your javascript snippet into your html resources (if they are locally) instead of manually adding it using `evalJS`.

Please note that there is an issue on android that you can't use local images (resources folder) in your webview when you provide the content via `html` property.

Comment: Hi Woo, sorry for late reply, and thanks for your comment,
I am writing webview.evalJS in load method(as I mentioned above) so I can be sure that data is loaded(so I think if data is loaded or not is out of scope now.) Now when I use webview.html(same html) I can swipe my webview(touchstart and touchmove events are called) but if I use webview.url instead of webview.html these events are not triggered. Kindly also note that this is the case only with iOS in android I am able to swipe my webview :). Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not have control on this files so I can not manually put these events into html files. I am unzipping one file(epub file) and then saving html files in applicationdatadirectory and then accessing these files one by one.

Comment: well load means that data is available it doesnt mean that the site has rendered. So maybe you should put the part in your evalJS within the `$(document).ready` wrapper of jQuery...

Comment: I am using javascript as shown above, not any solution with javascript?

Comment: and this is working perfectly in android I have also mentioned that also if data is loaded and script is added don't you think swipe should work.

Comment: You could try to inject your function integrated in this `$(document).ready` otherwise there will be no JS solution.